# I want to setup varnish to improve the performance of these websites

Tags: caching, varnish

I am hosting LAMP websites on rackspace. 
I want to setup varnish to improve the performance of these websites.
But I dont want to touch the client LAMP infrastructure. How can I architect that?
I understand I can have all http requests pointed to my varnish server but won't that increase latencies as the 2 servers are not hosted on the same server? load balancing may help as well I guess.

Answer (score -1):

There is no "general magic" to improve the performance of "any website". If it would exist, it would be baked into LAMP/J2EE/YourWebFrameworkHere and my initial statement would be true again.

But, if you know the specifics of your website, in most cases you can increase its performance (I've witnessed accelerations with factors between 1 to 1000). It is true that load-balancing increases latency, but you gain processing power and (if setup correctly) availability (if one server goes down, the other takes over). And with Varnish, you have a separate layer to  *cache* a response (no back-end work) and/or *manipulate* some cache-related HTTP headers and/or *compress* the response. What I like about Varnish is that you don't have to touch your existing architecture (this fits your question).

My question to you is: what are you trying to optimize, where's the bottleneck? I can recommend a book like "High Performance Web Sites (O'Reilly)" to get to know the subject a little bit better (and to enable you to ask a more specific question).